# Scala - can a lambda parameter match a tuple?

Tags: scala

So say i have some list like

```
val l = List((1, "blue"), (5, "red"), (2, "green"))
```

And then i want to filter one of them out, i can do something like

```
val m = l.filter(item => {
    val (n, s) = item          // "unpack" the tuple here
    n != 2
}
```

Is there any way i can "unpack" the tuple as the parameter to the lambda directly, instead of having this intermediate `item` variable?

Something like the following would be ideal, but eclipse tells me `wrong number of parameters; expected=1`

```
val m = l.filter( (n, s) => n != 2 )
```

Any help would be appreciated - using 2.9.0.1

Answer (score 105, accepted):

This is about the closest you can get:

```
 val m = l.filter { case (n, s) => n != 2 }
```

It's basically pattern matching syntax inside an anonymous [PartialFunction](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/PartialFunction.html). There are also the `tupled` methods in `Function` object and traits, but they are just a wrapper around this pattern matching expression.

Comment: You can replace `s` by `_` as it is never used.

Answer (score 20):

Hmm although Kipton has a good answer. You can actually make this shorter by doing.

```
val l = List((1, "blue"), (5, "red"), (2, "green"))
val m = l.filter(_._1 != 2)
```

Comment: Shorter does not make it better. This makes sense for very trivial examples, but for more complex stuff Kipton's example will lead to more readable code.

Comment: I downvoted this (5 years later) because it doesn't actually answer my question. My question was how to unpack a tuple, not how to filter a list.

Comment: I think having both answers here is helpful. I would argue this approach is better for the simple case. Even if it doesn't answer the actual question, someone landing here may not know this. And the accepted answer of course directly answers the question.

Answer (score 10):

There are a bunch of options:

```
for (x <- l; (n,s) = x if (n != 2)) yield x
l.collect{ case x @ (n,s) if (n != 2) => x }
l.filter{ case (n,s) => n != 2 }
l.unzip.zipped.map((n,s) => n != 2).zip   // Complains that zip is deprecated
```

Answer (score 10):

```
val m = l.filter( (n, s) => n != 2 )
```

... is a type mismatch because that lambda defines a

- `Function2[String,Int,Boolean]` with two parameters instead of
- `Function1[(String,Int),Boolean]` with one `Tuple2[String,Int]` as its  parameter.

You can convert between them like this:

```
val m = l.filter( ((n, s) => n != 2).tupled )
```

Answer (score 1):

I've pondered the same, and came to your question today.

I'm not very fond of the partial function approaches (anything having `case`) since they imply that there could be more entry points for the logic flow. At least to me, they tend to blur the intention of the code. On the other hand, I really do want to go straight to the tuple fields, like you.

Here's a solution I drafted today. It seems to work, but I haven't tried it in production, yet.

```
object unTuple {
  def apply[A, B, X](f: (A, B) => X): (Tuple2[A, B] => X) = {
    (t: Tuple2[A, B]) => f(t._1, t._2)
  }
  def apply[A, B, C, X](f: (A, B, C) => X): (Tuple3[A, B, C] => X) = {
    (t: Tuple3[A, B, C]) => f(t._1, t._2, t._3)
  }
  //...
}

val list = List( ("a",1), ("b",2) )
val list2 = List( ("a",1,true), ("b",2,false) )

list foreach unTuple( (k: String, v: Int) =>
  println(k, v)
)

list2 foreach unTuple( (k: String, v: Int, b: Boolean) =>
  println(k, v, b)
)
```

Output:

```
(a,1)
(b,2)
(a,1,true)
(b,2,false)
```

Maybe this turns out to be useful. The `unTuple` object should naturally be put aside in some tool namespace.

*Addendum:*

Applied to your case:

```
val m = l.filter( unTuple( (n:Int,color:String) =>
    n != 2
))
```