# Map a variable of type of Pair -- impossible

Tags: scala

This seems not logical for me:

```
scala> val a = Map((1, "111"), (2, "222"))
a: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> 111, 2 -> 222)

scala> val b = a.map((key, value) => value)
<console>:8: error: wrong number of parameters; expected = 1
       val b = a.map((key, value) => value)
                                  ^
scala> val c = a.map(x => x._2)
c: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[String] = List(111, 222)
```

I know that I can say `val d = a.map({ case(key, value) => value })`

But why isn't it possible to say    `a.map((key, value) => value)` ? There is **only one argument** there of type `Tuple2[Int, String]` or `Pair of Int, String`. What's the difference between `a.map((key, value) => value)` and `a.map(x => x._2)` ?

**UPDATE**:

`val myTuple2 = (1, 2)` -- this is one variable, correct?

`for ( (k, v) <- a ) yield v` -- `(k, v)` is also only one variable, correct?

`map((key, value) => value)` -- 2 variables. weird.

So how do I specify a variable of type `Tuple2` (or any other type) in `map` without using `case`?

**UPDATE2:**

What's wrong with that?

`Map((1, "111"), (2, "222")).map( ((x,y):Tuple2[Int, String]) => y)` -- wrong

`Map((1, "111"), (2, "222")).map( ((x):Tuple2[Int, String]) => x._2)` -- ok

Comment: There is only one variable of type `Tuple2[Int, String]`. map has signature `def map[B](f: (A) ⇒ B): Map[B]` -- it accepts function that takes **one** variable of type A and produces **one** output variable of type B (and `x => x._2` is an example of such function, whereas `(key, value) => value` is not)

Comment: @om-nom-nom, `(key, value)` -- is one variable of type Tuple2.

Comment: if that was true `List(1,2,3,4).reduce((x,y) => x + y)` wouldn't be possible

Comment: @om-nom-nom, how many variables are here `val myVal = (1, 2)` ?

Comment: @MariusKavansky, om-nom-nom is 100% right.  Trust me.

Comment: @cmbaxter, yes, my main man!

Comment: So then why not something like: `a.map { x => val (key, value) = x; value }` to destructure them (as om-nom-nom has said).
Yes, it's more verbose than what you'd hoped for, but it has the same intent.  Also, I'm curoious as to why a "case" is out of the question, as it seems to do what one would expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, you still not convinced. In cases like this it is pretty reasonable to fallback to the source of the truth (well, kinda): **The Holy Specification** (aka, Scala Language Specification).

[image]

So, in anonymous function parameters are treated on individual basis, not as a whole tuple band (and it is pretty smart, otherwise, how would you call the anonymous function with 2, ... n parameters?).

At the same time

```
val x = (1, 2)
```

is a single item of type Tiple2[Int,Int] (if you're interested you may find corresponding section of spec as well).

```
for ( (k, v) <- a ) yield v
```

In this case you have one variable unpacked to two variables. It is similar to

```
val x = (1, 2) // one variable -- tuple
val (y,z) = x  // two integer variables unpacked from one
```

Some call this *destructuring assignment* and this is a particular case of pattern matching. And you've already provided another example of pattern matching in action:

```
a.map({ case(key, value) => value })
```

Which we can read as *map accepts a function produced by a partial function literal, which enables use of pattern matching*.

Comment: So how do I specify a variable of type Tuple2 (or any other type) in map without using case?

Comment: @MariusKavansky currently there is no other funky way (if I got you right: you want to have `for ((k,v) <- m) yield v`-like syntax for .map without using *case* and explicit adressing). I've seen a thread on ML but it is full of contradictions and corner cases, so I doubt you could do this in foreseeable future.

Comment: @MariusKavansky I couldn't find thread I've talked about, but [there is one another](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/scala-debate/pt9pqYS0S7g/discussion)

Answer (score 2):

You're basically asking this same questions:

[Scala - can a lambda parameter match a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163676/scala-can-a-lambda-parameter-match-a-tuple)

You've already listed most of the options they listed there, including the accepted answer of using a PartialFunction.

However, since you're using your lambda in a `map` function, you could use a `for` comprehension instead:

```
for ( (k, v) <- a ) yield v
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`Function2.tupled`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function2) method to fix your lambda's type:

```
scala> val a = Map((1, "111"), (2, "222"))
a: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> 111, 2 -> 222)
scala> a.map( ((k:Int,v:String) => v).tupled )
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[String] = List(111, 222)
```

---

To answer your question in your thread with om-nom-nom above, look at this output:

```
scala> ( (x:Int,y:String) => y ).getClass.getSuperclass
res0: Class[?0] forSome { type ?0 >: ?0; type ?0 <: (Int, String) => String } = class scala.runtime.AbstractFunction2
```

Notice that the superclass of the anonymous function `(x:Int,y:String) => y` is `Function2[Int, String, String]`, not `Function1[(Int, String), String]`.

Comment: it's not what I'm asking about.

Comment: @MariusKavansky - Actually, that's exactly what you're asking—you just don't realize it! You should listen to om-nom-nom.

Comment: @MariusKavansky - Yes, that's a much better question—and the answer is in the thread I linked you to. You _have_ to do some sort of pattern matching / destructuring. Look at om-nom-nom's answer to see how the Scala lang spec says `(x,y)` in `(x,y)=>y` is a _parameter list_ and not a _tuple_.

Answer (score -2):

You can use pattern matching (or partial function, in this instance this is the same), notice angular brackets:

```
val b = a.map{ case (key, value) => value }
```